# Three tables, two foreign keys and one confused programmer

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So, I have myself all confused with how to pull info from three tables. Let me set this up fairly clearly (I hope)...

I have three tables `FoodTruck`, `MenuItems`, and `Ingredients`. Each food truck can have multiple menuItems (has a truckID column tied to the FoodTruck truckID) and each menuItem can have multiple ingredients (menuID column tied to the MenuItem menuID).

So, I am thoroughly confused on the mysql command to get the information I truly want (joins are still fairly confusing to me) because in the end I would LIKE to be able to show a user the Food Truck's menu. It would look like one big menu consisting of menuItems which include ingredients.

If there is a select query that would get all of that information, what would the output be comprised of? I mean, how would it be presented? An array of the menuItems and then an array of the ingredients? If I got the info I could figure out how to deal with it as I am using JDBC...

Forgot to add: in the Menu table there are the columns (primary key: menuID, foodName, price, foodType, specialComments)... I need all of those. In the Ingredients table, I have name and menuID but I really only need to display name.

I have most of the queries done that I need. It is just that I am trying to display the full menu now. I am using the DAO design and prepared statements to sanitize the input. In doing that, I was hoping to be able to use a join or somehow get all of that pertinent info without resorting to several queries to my database

Comment: Have you written any JDBC based code?

Comment: JDBC batch? No, I am new to JDBC as a whole. I will look into that if you think it would help

Comment: If it's your first use of JDBC,  then start with a single table.

Comment: Well, I would like to use one table, but my project dictates using more that one. Like I describe above, I need to hold multiple menuItems for each food truck and each menuItem has multiple ingredients. How could you do that with one table?

Comment: Query results will most likely be loaded into a List of your custom objects.

Comment: So I have most of the sql done that I need. It is just that I am trying to display the full menu now. I am using the DAO design and I am using prepared statements to sanitize my input. In doing that, I was hoping to be able to use a join or somehow get all of that pertinent info without resorting to several queries to my database

Comment: I mean,  start with a simpler task than your actual project.  When you have it working,  then do the real stuff.

Comment: Not sure where the relation to JDBC is, like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_innerjoin.htm for example, the magic lies in the right SQL statements. It's very likely that there is a rather simpler select statement to join all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with one query, using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  * // I used *, you should modify it if you want to better control the output
FROM FoodTruck ft
LEFT JOIN MenuItems mi
  ON mi.truckID = ft.truckID
LEFT JOIN Indgredient ind
  ON ind.menuID = mi.menuID
```

Left join will keep records from the table on the left even no rows can be found in the table on the right.

Take note that rows from `FoodTruck` are likely to duplicate because you have more than one menu items for each truck. The same will also happend to `MenuItem`.

Comment: Luke, thank you, I will try this. I have one question, though. If I don't really need any columns specifically from FoodTruck (i just need each menuItem and subsequently each of their ingredients), is it possible to add a `WHERE` clause? 
`SELECT (specific things) FROM FoodTruck ft LEFT JOIN... LEFT    JOIN... WHERE truckID = whatever`

Comment: Nevermind... didn't need it... all I needed to do was specify only the columns I needed! Thank you... and for anyone that needs an example, here is what my final query was:
`SELECT mi.foodName, mi.price, mi.calories, mi.specialComments, ind.ingredient FROM FoodTruck ft LEFT JOIN Menu mi ON mi.truckID = ft.truckID LEFT JOIN Ingredients ind ON ind.menuID = mi.menuID;`